# How to find the href attribute using VBA/selenium/chrome?

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, href, screen-scraping

I am fairly new to web scraping and I started with Selenium in VBA/Excel using Chrome. My target elements are the menu items.

In some websites I can find the elements but I can't get their "href". Here is the [destination website](https://www.beytoote.com/). I want the "href" of the menu items in the right side of the page.

This is what I tried:

```
    ' geting the menus, working well:
        Set mnus = bot1.FindElementsByClass("topmenu") 

        MenuCounter = 0
        For Each mnu In mnus
     'getting the href, fails
            lnk = mnu.Attribute("href")
```

I also tried some other ways but no success.

This is a screen shot of the inspect:
[image]

Note that I don't only want the href for this specific element (whose href is "art"). I also want the href of other equivalent menu items (except for the first item).

Comment: More information is needed. More code. More pics/information on how it is not working. Since you are new to Web Scraping, maybe you can look at Beautiful Soup and Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href value is inside anchor tag Not li element.You need to target anchor tag.Use following css selector.

```
Set mnus = bot1.FindElementsByCssSelector("li.topmenu >a[href]")    
MenuCounter = 0
For Each mnu In mnus
    lnk = mnu.Attribute("href")
```

Or To get all menus link try this.

## To get all menus link

```
Set mnus = bot1.FindElementsByCssSelector("ul.topmenu a[href]")
MenuCounter = 0
For Each mnu In mnus
    lnk = mnu.Attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was exaclty what I needed. And after reading your response i have been searching for hours to realize the syntax. I found good material in https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp     so what I learned is this syntax: *set x= bot.FindelementsbyCss(" element.class > childrenelement [ desired attribute]")* . Am I getting it right?

Comment: Possibly yes.I don’t have much knowledge about VBA.But the css selector is correct just check the syntax.

Comment: I also found out that i can use this selector for the Menu items: #css3menu1 > li > a   .  Tha gives me all Menu items (including the first one) I guess I have learnt the basics of the concept. Many thanks Kunduk